# Price moneyness vs spread moneyness for credit index options (CDX HY)

Tags: options, volatility, credit

Is spread moneyness equivalent to price moneyness for volatility surfaces of CDX HY? In other words, is the ISDA converter a linear transformation?

I have market data that I need to convert to input in Black Swap Yield.

Thanks!